# Changing hidden input element value on the fly using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Used one hidden element to capture changed value

and change the element value using jquery

```
changeValue(no){
   $('#mobileno').val(no);
}
```

and then pass the value to ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type: 'post',       
    data: '{"id":"1", "mobileno":$("#mobileno").val()}',
    success: function(data, status) {
    console.log("Success!!");        
    },    
});
```

mobileno  field always shows empty value value while posting, if i am used alert in change value method then it is working fine

```
changeValue(no){
 $('#mobileno').val(no);    
 alert( $('#mobileno').val());
}
```

then it is working fine, your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've quoted your JS object making it into a string

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type: 'post',       
    data: '{"id":"1", "mobileno":$("#mobileno").val()}',
    ------^                                            ^--------
    success: function(data, status) {
    console.log("Success!!");        
    },    
});
```

Use this

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type: 'post',       
    data: {"id":"1", "mobileno": $("#mobileno").val() },
    success: function(data, status) {
    console.log("Success!!");        
    }    
});
```

Comment: and perhaps removing the comma for the end of the .ajax() method parameters ?

Comment: @ManseUK that shouldn't affect any of the newer browsers, but good point. Updated.

Comment: This is always the first thing i check - ive been bitten by IE many times !

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use single quots when assigning value to `data` parameter. Try this;

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type: 'post',       
    data: {"id":"1", "mobileno":$("#mobileno").val()},
    success: function(data, status) {
    console.log("Success!!");        
    }
});
```

By the way, there is a trailing comma after `success` parameter which might cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ajax call to :

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type: 'post',       
    data: {"id":"1", "mobileno":$("#mobileno").val()}, //this line changed
    success: function(data, status) {
    console.log("Success!!");        
    }   // removed comma
});
```

Remove the quotes on the data line and the comma from the last bracket

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type: 'post',       
    data: "id=1&mobileno="+$("#mobileno").val(),
    success: function(data, status) {
    console.log("Success!!");        
    },    
});
```